# Drag and match objects

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, elasticity

I want to make a game which needs to drag an object (`UIView` class object) and intersect with an another object (`UIButton`) and the same time an event generates , and checks the matching of object is right or wrong.

If wrong the objects come back to its position.

The touch and drag I have done with the object but elasticity of the objects position is not working properly ? Any example or help Please

Comment: You're too vague.  What doesn't work?  The drag, or the return to position? Have you looked at CoreAnimation?  Need more info.

Comment: Yeh i used core animation and touch and move methods but still the animation of dragging the object not working properly, may be my lack of knowledge in COCOA animation..

Comment: Actually I am looking for something as a tile on the ipad screen that is situated on the particular coordinates, while dragging and touching if we leave it it just come back to it's position with elasticity animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using standard (non-GL) programming, you can use the object's frame to check if the objects intersect.  There's a call for it. You can take the relevant points of one object and check if they are inside the other object's polygon.  If they are, then you have a collision.  The Quartz 2D drawing tools have lots of intersection methods for these types of objects.